# Why is '127.0.0.1' trying to connect to '10.0.0.2'?

Tags: networking

On a LAN each computer is assigned a different IP address each morning. When I installed Kubuntu 12.10 the IP address assigned to the machine was `10.0.0.2`, but today it is `10.0.0.1`. When I try to connect to `http://127.0.0.1` in Firefox I see in the status bar `Connecting to 10.0.0.2`. However, there is no mention of that address in the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       bruno

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Note that setting the DHCP server to assign the same IP address per MAC address cannot be done as the router is unplugged each evening (electrical issues in the building) and loses the settings.

Comment: Which web browser are you using? Please add that information to your question.

Comment: @jdthood: Thanks, I added that the web browser is Firefox.

Comment: I don't know why Firefox is trying to connect to 10.* when you type in 127.0.0.1. But you may be able to work around the problem of it connecting to the wrong IP address by making Firefox clear its cache.

Comment: Thanks, jdhood. I've forced the IP address back to `10.0.0.2` so that I could work so I cannot test now, but I think that you're right. Please post your comment an answer so that I could accept it. I will test this later when less fires are burning.

Comment: Well, we're not sure that the solution works yet. Report back here and I'll craft a suitable answer. :)  Also, the more interesting question is, indeed, why trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 results in "connecting to 10.0...".

Comment: You were right, jdthood. Please post your comment as an answer so that I might accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Done. BTW, have you figured out why Firefox is getting redirected from 127.0.0.1 to 10.*?

Comment: I suspect but have not proven that Firefox was _once_ redirected as such as is therefore caching the redirect. The Mozilla devs have made some questionable "optimization" changes in the past few versions (mostly in the area of memory management and UI responsiveness) and this might be one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous IP address was 10.0.0.2 and now it is 10.0.0.1. If Firefox is now trying to connect to 10.0.0.2 then it must have previously cached that address. Clear Firefox's cache; whatever mechanism previously redirected Firefox from 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.2 should now redirect Firefox to 10.0.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

If `http://127.0.0.1` gets redirected to `http://10.0.0.2` then it means that the web server listening on `127.0.0.1:80` is doing such redirect.

So the fault is not of the TCP stack implementation of Linux, nor is there anything wrong with `/etc/hosts`. (Do not confuse **host names** with **IP addresses**: host names are resolved, IP addresses are not. In other words, there is no way to make `127.0.0.1` "resolve" to `10.0.0.2` without using a high-level protocol such as HTTP, which allows redirection from one IP address to another.)

Try using `wget` which will give you many useful details. You should see something like the following.

```
$ wget http://127.0.0.1
--2013-01-09 15:55:38--  http://127.0.0.1
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://10.0.0.2 [following]
...
```

Of course, the exact output will vary depending on the situation. However, if you see a similar output, it is evidence that a web server is doing the redirect.

Therefore, to solve the problem, you should look into your web server configuration.

Comment: Thank you, I see via `wget` that there is no redirect. However, recursively grepping `/etc/apache2/` for the string `10.0.0.2` produces no results, either.

Comment: Does `wget` work correctly (i.e. which IP address does it use)? The reason I'm asking is this: if `wget` works correctly, then the problem may be in your web browser (and if this is the case, clearing the cache should help). Please, would you kindly paste the output of `wget` in your question and also specify which browser are you using? Thanks!

Comment: Oops, sorry. I just noticed that the web browser is already specified in your question.

Comment: I do agree that the web browser is the issue. I've worked around the issue to get some work done today, but I'm pretty sure that jdthood's comment regarding the browser cache may be right. He won't post it as an answer for me to accept until I test it, though, and I don't know when I'll have opportune to mess up this LAN on purpose!